# Redux state changed but component props is not updating

Tags: react-redux, antd

I am using redux to control an Ant Design Modal component with a boolean state. Basically it has a button that dispatch action to change the state, and the component will read the state value.

The state is changed properly but the component props value is not updating accordingly. Not sure why it is not working.

I have tried different approaches in reducer like creating a new boolean object to avoid mutating the state but no luck.

myAction.js

```
export const modalVisibilityOn = () => ({
    type: 'MODAL_ON'
})

export const modalVisibilityOff = () => ({
    type: 'MODAL_OFF'
})
```

myReducer.js

```
const modalVisibility = (state = false, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case 'MODAL_ON':
            return true
        case 'MODAL_OFF':
            return false
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default modalVisibility
```

myRootReducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import modalVisibility from './signPage/myReducer'

export default combineReducers({
    modalVisibility
})
```

myModal.js

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Modal, Input } from 'antd';

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { modalVisibilityOff } from '../../reducers/signPage/myAction'

class myModal extends React.Component {

    render() {
    const { visibility, handleOk, handleCancel } = this.props;

    myModal.propTypes = {
      visibility: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
      handleOk: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      handleCancel: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        }

        return (
            <Modal
              title="Sign"
              visible={visibility}
              onOk={handleOk}
              onCancel={handleCancel}
              closable={false}
            >
              <p>Please input your staff ID</p>
              <Input addonBefore="Staff ID" />
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    visibility: state.modalVisibility
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  handleOk: () => dispatch(modalVisibilityOff()),
  handleCancel: () => dispatch(modalVisibilityOff()),
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps
)(myModal)
```

myModalContainer.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Input } from "antd";
import { Button } from 'antd';
import { Row, Col } from 'antd';
import { Typography } from 'antd';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import myModal from '../../dialogs/signPage/myModal';

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { modalVisibilityOn } from '../../reducers/signPage/myAction'

class myModalContainer extends React.Component {

  render() {
        const { Title } = Typography;

        const { onClick } = this.props;

    myModalContainer.propTypes = {
      onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
        }

    return (
            <div className="search-container-parent">
                <Row className="search-container">
                    <Col className="search-col1" xs={24} sm={12}>
                        <Input size="large" style={{width:'40%'}} id="issueReturnNo" placeholder="QR code here"/>
                        <Button size="large">SEARCH</Button>
                        <div className="signBtn-div">
                            <Button size="large" type="primary" onClick={onClick} >SIGN</Button>
                            <myModal />
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs={24} sm={12}>
                        <Title className="issueLog-title" level={3} style={{color:"#F08080"}}>Issue</Title>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
    );
  }
}

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
        onClick: () => dispatch(modalVisibilityOn())
    })

  export default connect(
    null, mapDispatchToProps
  )(myModalContainer);
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import rootReducer from './myRootReducer'

const store = createStore(rootReducer,window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
 document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I expect the visibility props on `myModal.js` would be `true` when the sign button on `myModalContainer.js` is clicked, but the it keep showing `false`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of researches and trials, It turns out that my code has no problem..

The reason why it is not working as expected, is due to the `redux` and `react-redux` version. After switching `package.json` dependencies versions back to the one that redux official tutorial are using, the application is running without any problem.

In case anyone have the same problem, here is the version I am using now for my app in `npm`:

```
redux: ^3.5.2
react-redux: ^5.0.7
```

---

Update:

Just found out that the cause of the problem comes from conflicts between older version modules and newer version modules.

Therefore by updating all the dependencies in `package.json` to the latest version, the app can also run smoothly. It is not necessary to downgrade `react-redux` and `redux`.